# Sequential number and maximum value using DENSE_RANK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, max, dense-rank

I am using `DENSE_RANK` to assign a sequential number to different values of `[y]` within each group `[x]`. It adds a new column `[rank]`.

I also want a new column showing the maximum rank `[y]` (highest sequence number) within each `[x]` e.g. `[highest_rank]`. Is there a way to obtain this new column at the same time, without having to create a separate table for maximum values then joining the tables together?

```
SELECT [x],[y],[rank]
INTO table2
FROM
(
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [x] ORDER BY [y] ) AS [rank]
FROM table1
) tmp
```

Comment: You can apply a window function on `MAX` too, ie: `MAX (...) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [x] ORDER BY [y] ) AS [rank]
    FROM table1 
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT [x], [highest_rank]=MAX([rank])
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY [x]
)
SELECT cte1.[x],cte1.[y],cte1.[rank],cte2.[highest_rank]
FROM cte1 INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte2.[x]=cte1.[x];
```